# Making table using gridview

Tags: asp.net

[Is it possible for me to make this output using Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP1JO.png)

Actually I want to make the output of this using gridview but I encounter a problem with it, this is the sample code that I have used.

```
                <Columns>

                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="File" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("File_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part Number">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="PN" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PN") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial Number">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="SN" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SN") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Email" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Upload_Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ship Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Password" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ship_Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload by">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Password" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LoginID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>      
                            <asp:Linkbutton ID="btn_edit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteComfirmation">Edit</asp:Linkbutton>
                            <asp:Linkbutton ID="btn_delete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-md btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteComfirmation">Delete</asp:Linkbutton>

                        </ItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: I would recommend to use `ListView` which is newer and much more flexible. If `GridView` is the must then include `PlaceHolder`s in the last two `ItemTemplate`s and manage there visibility from the data. Side note `Bind` is useless for `Label` controls. Use `Eval` instead.

Comment: And what exactly is that problem?